# Android's PresetReverb doesn't work?

Tags: android, audioeffect

I'm developing a small audio player with support for Android's built-in audio effects (like EnvironmentalReverb). So far I was having a problem with having it launching without crashing and I solved the issue by adding a missing permission to AndroidManifest.xml. Now the problem is that I just don't hear any reverb.

Here's my code :

```
MediaPlayer player;
EnvironmentalReverb eReverb;
boolean enabled = true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.andthentocoda);
    /*
       PresetReverb pReverb    = new PresetReverb(1,0);
       player.attachAuxEffect(pReverb.getId());
       pReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
       pReverb.setEnabled(true);
       player.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
       */

       eReverb = new EnvironmentalReverb(1,0); 
       eReverb.setDecayHFRatio((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setDecayTime(10000);
       eReverb.setDensity((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setDiffusion((short) 1000);
       eReverb.setReverbLevel((short) -1000);
       eReverb.setEnabled(enabled);
       player.attachAuxEffect(eReverb.getId());
       player.setAuxEffectSendLevel(0.5f);

       player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void clicked(View v)
{
    enabled = !enabled;
    eReverb.setEnabled(enabled);
    Log.d("EFECT", "Effect " + (enabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}
```

Do you have any idea what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 0):

I attach the `audioTrack` instance to the `audioEffect` like this:

```
try {
    plateReverb = new PresetReverb(0, mAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId());
} catch (Throwable e){
    plateReverb = null;
}
if (plateReverb!=null){plateReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE);}
```

and of course you would have to replace `mAudioTrack.getAudioSessionId()` with `player.getAudioSessionId()`

But I don't know if that is why you can't hear it. Some devices do not support audio effects and you will see an error on the logcat.